# Using Silverlight 5 Beta but target version 4 of the Framework

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Is it possible to use the Silverlight 5 beta (and benefit from the debugging tools in Visual Studio) and still target version 4 in the same way? We would really like the debugging tools in VS but we cannot risk any new bugs that may be present in v5 of the framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it runs out of the box. I use the Silverlight 5 XAML debugging experience in a SL 4 project myself.

Visual Studio allows multitargeting for the Silverlight projects, but apparently always uses the last version of the debugging tools. Furthermore, I didn't see any bug.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the Silverlight bits and still target older versions, if that is what you are asking, as these are incremental builds (barring a new framework version, of which I know of none immediately planned). So the short answer is yes, you can do it.

The longer answer is you may still experience bugs. Perhaps not in your release product, which is you stated goal, but any addition of betaware presents a possible danger. So plan accordingly. Fortunately, you should be able to back out of this one fairly easy due to the way both Silverlight and VS work today.